# Sort an active record based on an array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sorting, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord @grid.

I have an Hash @numbers.

**rails console**

```
    1.9.3p385 :086 > Grids
     => Grids(unique_id: integer, price: float, availability: string,
     delivery: string, delivery_time: string, delivery_cost: float, 
     special_offers: text, warranty: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) 


    => @numbers
    =>{7=>114, 9=>21, 12=>7, 13=>31, 14=>51, 16=>43, 18=>48, 21=>6, 22=>18, 
       24=>69, 27=>47, 30=>47, 32=>31, 33=>36}
```

@numbers hash is nothing but unique_id => number of clicks

```
1.9.3p385 :091 > @no =  @numbers.sort_by{|k,v| v}.reverse.map{|i| i[0]} 
              => [7, 24, 14, 18, 30, 27, 16, 33, 13, 32, 9, 22, 12, 21]
```

@no is an array of unique_id.

@grid = Grid.all

```
@grid is an activeRecord, I want to sort this active record based 
on the order of @no which is nothing but the unique_id in @grid.
```

Im trying this,

```
@grid.sort_by{ |h| @no.index(h.unique_id) }
```

It's not working, it says,

> ArgumentError: comparison of NilClass with 14 failed

I understand there is some nil comparison going on. How to ignore this or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first create a hash from your grid relation indexed by id, and then perform a mapping from lookups on this index :

```
grid_index = @grid.index_by &:id
@no.map{|id| grid_index[id] } # possibly compact the resulting array after that
```

Comment: m_x, Im working on your solution, its kind of a bingo. Let me try it out in entirety and walk back!

Comment: Dude, How am i to ignore nils in my resulting array.

Comment: Forget nils, I will figure it out. Your solution worked beautifully. Thanks.

Comment: to get rid of the nils, call `compact` on the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `@grid` includes some `unique_id` which `@no` does not have.

Replace

```
@grid = Grid.all
```

With

```
@grid = Grid.all(:conditions=>["unique_id in (?)",@no])
```

Then

```
@grid.sort_by{ |h| @no.index(h.unique_id) }
```

Comment: Thats right shweta! Thanks. But Im creating the no using grid in my code. So strictly I want to order grid based on no. Am I alright?

Comment: you can perform `@grid.sort_by{ |h| @no.index(h.unique_id) }` after replacement.

Comment: when i wont have no during the creation of grid, how am i to use no in this condition....:conditions=>["unique_id in (?)",@no] ...?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but see m_x's solution, its very rich. Form an hash from active record with unique_id as the key. Now, build an array of activerecords using the value of no as the key to first formed hash. Great stuff!!

Comment: you want to help me more on this, I have to do a lot on this hash after sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@grid.where(:unique_id => @no).map(&:unique_id)
```

Comment: No, you dont get it. Check out m_x's solution and taste the essence of it.